# Checking a proof theorem of topology of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

- $x_0$ is a limit point of $S$ if and only if there exists a sequence $x_n\in S\backslash\left\{ x_0\right\} $ such that $\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=x_{0}$.

My proof trying. $\left( \Rightarrow\right)$ Assume $x_0$ is a limit point of $S$. Let $\delta=1/n$ as $n\in\mathbb{N^{>0}}$. Then, by the definition, for any $\delta >0$ such that

$\left( x_{0},-\dfrac {1}{n},x_{0}+\dfrac {1}{n}\right) \cap S\backslash\left\{ x_0\right\}\neq \emptyset$.

Thus for each $n$, choose $x_n\in\left( x_{0},-\dfrac {1}{n},x_{0}+\dfrac {1}{n}\right) \cap S\backslash\left\{ x_0\right\}$. This means that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

$\left| x_{n}-x_{0}\right| <\dfrac {1}{n}$, that is, $\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=x_{0}$.

$\left( \Leftarrow\right)$ Assume there exists a sequence $x_n\in S\backslash\left\{ x_0\right\} $ such that $\lim _{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=x_{0}$. This means that, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $x_n\in\left( x_{0},-\dfrac {1}{n},x_{0}+\dfrac {1}{n}\right) \cap S\backslash\left\{ x_0\right\}$. Since, it is convergent, it cannot be empty set. Therefore, $x_0$ is a limit point of $S$.

So, we are done.

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: Why would $x_n \in (x_0 -1/n, x_0+1/n)$ for every $n$? What if $x_n = 5/n$ for example.

Comment: @Demophilus Which case, LHS/RHS?

Comment: @Demophilus actualy, it would be $n>N$ for RHS.

Comment: For proving $\impliedby$ it is enough to observe that for every $\epsilon>0$ we will have $x_n\in(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ for $n$ large enough. As @Demophilus noticed; there is no argumentation for $x_n\in(x_0-1/n,x_0+1/n)$, and fortunately you also don't need that.

Comment: In your second proof, you say that if there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=x_0$ then $x_n \in (x_0-1/n, x_0+1/n)$ for all $n$. This need not be true at all. The best you can say is that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_m \in (x_0-1/n, x_0+1/n)$ for all $m \geq N$.

Comment: @Demophilus Thanks for comment

Comment: @drhab thanks for comment